# Declaring a numpy array with cython strangely generates a lot of overhead

Tags: python, numpy, cython

I'm rewriting some of my Python code using Cython.

Following the suggestions [in the documentation](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/numpy.html) I started substituting my python arrays with the optimized cython definition.

In particular, the following is supposed to be the 'best' way of declaring a numpy array:

```
# cython: profile=True
# cython: boundscheck=False
# cython: wraparound=False

import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

cpdef test():

    cdef np.ndarray[np.int_t, ndim=1] seeds_idx = np.empty(10, dtype=np.int)

    pass
```

However, the html file generated by profiling the code above via `cython -a my_file.pyx` shows the following:

```
+10:     cdef np.ndarray[np.int_t, ndim=1] seeds_idx = np.empty(10, dtype=np.int)
  __pyx_t_1 = __Pyx_GetModuleGlobalName(__pyx_n_s_np); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_1)) __PYX_ERR(0, 10, __pyx_L1_error)
  __Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_1);
  __pyx_t_2 = __Pyx_PyObject_GetAttrStr(__pyx_t_1, __pyx_n_s_empty); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_2)) __PYX_ERR(0, 10, __pyx_L1_error)
  __Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_2);
  __Pyx_DECREF(__pyx_t_1); __pyx_t_1 = 0;
  __pyx_t_1 = PyDict_New(); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_1)) __PYX_ERR(0, 10, __pyx_L1_error)
  __Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_1);
  __pyx_t_3 = __Pyx_GetModuleGlobalName(__pyx_n_s_np); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_3)) __PYX_ERR(0, 10, __pyx_L1_error)
  __Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_3);
  __pyx_t_4 = __Pyx_PyObject_GetAttrStr(__pyx_t_3, __pyx_n_s_int); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_4)) __PYX_ERR(0, 10, __pyx_L1_error)
  __Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_4);
  __Pyx_DECREF(__pyx_t_3); __pyx_t_3 = 0;
  if (PyDict_SetItem(__pyx_t_1, __pyx_n_s_dtype, __pyx_t_4) < 0) __PYX_ERR(0, 10, __pyx_L1_error)
  __Pyx_DECREF(__pyx_t_4); __pyx_t_4 = 0;
  __pyx_t_4 = __Pyx_PyObject_Call(__pyx_t_2, __pyx_tuple_, __pyx_t_1); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_4)) __PYX_ERR(0, 10, __pyx_L1_error)
  __Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_4);
  __Pyx_DECREF(__pyx_t_2); __pyx_t_2 = 0;
  __Pyx_DECREF(__pyx_t_1); __pyx_t_1 = 0;
  if (!(likely(((__pyx_t_4) == Py_None) || likely(__Pyx_TypeTest(__pyx_t_4, __pyx_ptype_5numpy_ndarray))))) __PYX_ERR(0, 10, __pyx_L1_error)
  __pyx_t_5 = ((PyArrayObject *)__pyx_t_4);
  {
    __Pyx_BufFmt_StackElem __pyx_stack[1];
    if (unlikely(__Pyx_GetBufferAndValidate(&__pyx_pybuffernd_seeds_idx.rcbuffer->pybuffer, (PyObject*)__pyx_t_5, &__Pyx_TypeInfo_nn___pyx_t_5numpy_int_t, PyBUF_FORMAT| PyBUF_STRIDES, 1, 0, __pyx_stack) == -1)) {
      __pyx_v_seeds_idx = ((PyArrayObject *)Py_None); __Pyx_INCREF(Py_None); __pyx_pybuffernd_seeds_idx.rcbuffer->pybuffer.buf = NULL;
      __PYX_ERR(0, 10, __pyx_L1_error)
    } else {__pyx_pybuffernd_seeds_idx.diminfo[0].strides = __pyx_pybuffernd_seeds_idx.rcbuffer->pybuffer.strides[0]; __pyx_pybuffernd_seeds_idx.diminfo[0].shape = __pyx_pybuffernd_seeds_idx.rcbuffer->pybuffer.shape[0];
    }
  }
  __pyx_t_5 = 0;
  __pyx_v_seeds_idx = ((PyArrayObject *)__pyx_t_4);
  __pyx_t_4 = 0;
/* … */
  __pyx_tuple_ = PyTuple_Pack(1, __pyx_int_10); if (unlikely(!__pyx_tuple_)) __PYX_ERR(0, 10, __pyx_L1_error)
  __Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_tuple_);
  __Pyx_GIVEREF(__pyx_tuple_);
```

This was obtained on Python 2.7 with cython 0.24 and numpy 1.10.4.

On the other hand, the very simple declaration `seeds_idx = np.empty(10)` results in:

```
+10:     seeds_idx = np.empty(10)
  __pyx_t_1 = __Pyx_GetModuleGlobalName(__pyx_n_s_np); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_1)) __PYX_ERR(0, 10, __pyx_L1_error)
  __Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_1);
  __pyx_t_2 = __Pyx_PyObject_GetAttrStr(__pyx_t_1, __pyx_n_s_empty); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_2)) __PYX_ERR(0, 10, __pyx_L1_error)
  __Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_2);
  __Pyx_DECREF(__pyx_t_1); __pyx_t_1 = 0;
  __pyx_t_1 = __Pyx_PyObject_Call(__pyx_t_2, __pyx_tuple_, NULL); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_1)) __PYX_ERR(0, 10, __pyx_L1_error)
  __Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_1);
  __Pyx_DECREF(__pyx_t_2); __pyx_t_2 = 0;
  __pyx_v_seeds_idx = __pyx_t_1;
  __pyx_t_1 = 0;
/* … */
  __pyx_tuple_ = PyTuple_Pack(1, __pyx_int_10); if (unlikely(!__pyx_tuple_)) __PYX_ERR(0, 10, __pyx_L1_error)
  __Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_tuple_);
  __Pyx_GIVEREF(__pyx_tuple_);
```

What is going wrong here (if any)? Thanks!

Comment: There is nothing wrong, numpy arrays are complex (yet very efficient) data structures. You can try using [typed memoryviews](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/memoryviews.html) instead anyway, they are usually faster and can be easily converted to numpy arrays.

Comment: The other point worth making is that there __is__ overhead in assigning the array. Using the array of quick but assigning it can be a little slower so try not to do it unnecessarily.

Comment: I see, so there is a small overhead during declaration but a much faster assigning/accessing/etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comment stated, there is nothing wrong going on here so no need to worry. Also, remember that you are checking the code generated for a simple assignment, any differences won't affect performance.

A small errata though, in the second case `seeds_idx = np.empty(10)` should be changed to `seeds_idx = np.empty(10, dtype=np.int)` to match the first.

If you add that, then the dictionary that is created for storing the arguments of the function call (`np.empty`) is also added:

```
__pyx_t_1 = PyDict_New(); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_1)) __PYX_ERR(0, 8, __pyx_L1_error)
__Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_1);
```

the lookup for `np.int`:

```
__pyx_t_3 = __Pyx_GetModuleGlobalName(__pyx_n_s_np); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_3)) __PYX_ERR(0, 10, __pyx_L1_error)
__Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_3);
__pyx_t_4 = __Pyx_PyObject_GetAttrStr(__pyx_t_3, __pyx_n_s_int); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_4)) __PYX_ERR(0, 10, __pyx_L1_error)
__Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_4);
__Pyx_DECREF(__pyx_t_3); __pyx_t_3 = 0;
```

and the setting of the arguments in the newly created dictionary is done:

```
if (PyDict_SetItem(__pyx_t_1, __pyx_n_s_dtype, __pyx_t_4) < 0) __PYX_ERR(0, 8, __pyx_L1_error)
__Pyx_DECREF(__pyx_t_4); __pyx_t_4 = 0;
```

Other than these, the only difference between them is the following:

```
if (!(likely(((__pyx_t_4) == Py_None) || likely(__Pyx_TypeTest(__pyx_t_4, __pyx_ptype_5numpy_ndarray))))) __PYX_ERR(0, 10, __pyx_L1_error)
  __pyx_t_5 = ((PyArrayObject *)__pyx_t_4);
  {
    __Pyx_BufFmt_StackElem __pyx_stack[1];
    if (unlikely(__Pyx_GetBufferAndValidate(&__pyx_pybuffernd_seeds_idx.rcbuffer->pybuffer, (PyObject*)__pyx_t_5, &__Pyx_TypeInfo_nn___pyx_t_5numpy_int_t, PyBUF_FORMAT| PyBUF_STRIDES, 1, 0, __pyx_stack) == -1)) {
      __pyx_v_seeds_idx = ((PyArrayObject *)Py_None); __Pyx_INCREF(Py_None); __pyx_pybuffernd_seeds_idx.rcbuffer->pybuffer.buf = NULL;
      __PYX_ERR(0, 10, __pyx_L1_error)
    } else {__pyx_pybuffernd_seeds_idx.diminfo[0].strides = __pyx_pybuffernd_seeds_idx.rcbuffer->pybuffer.strides[0]; __pyx_pybuffernd_seeds_idx.diminfo[0].shape = __pyx_pybuffernd_seeds_idx.rcbuffer->pybuffer.shape[0];
    }
  }
```

Which, [as stated in the documentation you linked](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/numpy.html#efficient-indexing) is most likely performed in order to have fast access to the data buffer.

The best alternative, by far, is using [typed memoryviews](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/memoryviews.html). These are the native way and most likely the easiest way to work with arrays in cython. [Their performance is usually on par with numpy arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26189570/cython-are-typed-memoryviews-the-modern-way-to-type-numpy-arrays) and if not you can always switch between them easily.

Comment: Then my question is, what is the advantage on using a numpy array this way over declaring a dictionary directly?

Comment: I was a bit vague on the dictionary creation; a dictionary is created whenever you want to pass keyword args to a function, so in the case of the `np.empty(10, dtype=np.int)` a dictionary is created to store the arguments. In the case of `np.empty(10)` a dictionary isn't created. It is always advisable to declare the type of the array so Cython can optimize the generated `c` code based on it. I updated my answer to include some links on *typed memoryviews* which are the advisable way to do things in Cython.

Comment: Oh ok, just for the keywords...still a lot of overhead I suppose. On the matter of the typed memoryview I posted a new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37432076/cython-typed-memoryviews-what-they-really-are). Thanks Jim!