# Cython error thrown unexpectedly for buffer types which ARE function local variables

Tags: cython

Just learning Cython, and ran into an error I don't understand, well I don't understand why it is being thrown in the function below. The pure Python version works as expected.

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

ctypedef np.int8_t DTYPE_int8
ctypedef np.int64_t DTYPE_int64

cdef int fitness(np.ndarray[DTYPE_int8, ndim=1] c):
    
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_int8, ndim=1] a
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_int8, ndim=1] d1_cnts
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_int8, ndim=1] d2_cnts
    
    a = np.arange(N, dtype=np.int8)
    d1_cnts = np.unique(c - a, return_counts=True)[1]
    d2_cnts = np.unique(c + a, return_counts=True)[1]
    d1_cnts = sum(sum(range(n)) for n in d1_cnts)
    d2_cnts = sum(sum(range(n)) for n in d2_cnts)
    return d1_cnts + d2_cnts

pop = np.arange(N, dtype=np.int8)
print(fitness(pop))
```

I get the error "Buffer types only allowed as function local variables" for d1_cnts and d2_cnts. Both of these variables ARE function local variables (right?), so why does this error occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're captured in the generator expression in:

```
(sum(range(n)) for n in d1_cnts)
```

In this case the generator expression is immediately used by `sum` but Cython is worried about the general case where you might return the generator expression (with the captured variables).

Your two options are:

1. Use typed memoryviews, which are less restricted
2. Switch to a sum over a list comprehension, which doesn't capture variables.

I think Cython should end up optimizing out the generator expression fairly efficiently, but the error message comes at an earlier stage, before it realises that this is an option.

---

Also `sum(range(n))` should be replaceable with the triangle number formula (`(n-1)*n/2` I think), but that's a separate optimization

Comment: Simple as that eh? Thanks, it worked. Yes to the triangle number formula - something was bugging me about that! Are typed memoryviews recommended way to use cython? I know nothing about them.

Comment: Typed memoryviews are a more modern alternative to the `np.ndarray` syntax. They do much the same thing but are slightly more flexible in some ways: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37432076/cython-typed-memoryviews-what-they-really-are/37497998#37497998 for (too many) details. Pick whichever you prefer - mostly it doesn't make much difference.