# Using numpy masking in cython

Tags: python, numpy, cython

I'm trying to convert some of my Python code to Cython and experience some issues when I try to define a function as `cdef`.

Most of the issues boil down to masking not working as in Python. I wonder if this is a limitation of `cdef` (works fine if I leave it as `def`) or whether there's something I could do.

For instance this method

```
cdef func(double[:,:,:,:] arg1):
    mask = arg1 > 0
    ...
```

already fails with a compile error:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------ ...
    func (double[:,:,:,:] arg1):
        mask = arg1 > 0
                   ^
------------------------------------------------------------

cythonfile.pyx:43:20: Invalid types for '>' (double[:, :, :, :], long)
```

Comment: Shouldn't you define `cdef func(np.ndarray[np.float_t, ndim=4] arg1)`? Also `0` is a `long integer`. Replace it with `0.` to get a `float`.

Comment: @NilsWerner: I just tried and changed the type and that seems to do it. I had code with `double[:,:]` working before, so never thought about it, but for that code, I didn't use masking. I guess one needs to tell cython that this is a numpy array which allows masking. Thanks!

Comment: I guess `double[:, :]` only allows individual addressing of elements, but not vectorized operations like the one you are doing.

Comment: Yep, I think so too. I never used vectorised operations in Cython before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The docs consistently use `np.ndarray[...]` in function definitions](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/numpy.html) so I would change your function signature to

```
cdef func(np.ndarray[np.float_t, ndim=4] arg1):
```

Also, you are comparing a `float` array with an `long integer` constant. Change it to

```
mask = arg1 > 0.
```

to compare `float` with `float`.

Answer (score 1):

The `double[:,:,:,:]` notation specifies that the argument will be "interpreted" as [Typed Memoryview](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html#typed-memoryviews). These support a lot of operations but the **vectorized comparisons** are not supported.

However it's quite easy to interpret a memory-view as NumPy array inside the function:

```
import numpy as np

cdef func(double[:,:,:,:] arg1):
    arg1arr = np.asarray(arg1)
    mask = arg1arr > 0.
```

That doesn't even need a copy so it's basically "free" to do the `np.asarray` on the memory-view. That allows to combine the advantages of the memory-views with the vectorized operations that are possible on NumPy arrays.

However for vectorized operations you don't need Cython, you could do all the vectorized operations in a pure python function and only use Cython for the heavy-lifting that isn't possible with "normal NumPy" functions.

Comment: Is there any difference in terms of performance between passing in `np.ndarray` or `double[...]` arguments? You said the `np.asarray` creation is "free", but is that also true for other operations?

Comment: @orange That depends on your use-case. Several aspects are already covered here, for example ["Cython: are typed memoryviews the modern way to type numpy arrays?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26192382/5393381) or in some blogs ["Memoryview Benchmarks"](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/08/08/memoryview-benchmarks/). The problem with memoryviews is that some vectorized operations aren't available. On the other hand one doesn't need Cython for vectorized operations (because they are as fast as in Python).

Comment: @orange I've seen no performance difference between using the same code with ndarray and [:,:] formats on high speed math libraries

Comment: @Matt: Makes sense if converting to `np.ndarray` come for "free". Thanks for your clarification.